# QuickBlox login issue

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, quickblox

I am facing issues in QuickBlox and I am using the below code to log in.

```
QBRequest.logIn(withUserLogin: phoneNumber, password: password, successBlock: { response, user in
            // Success, do something

             print("Successfully signup:-\(user)")
        }, errorBlock: { response in
            // error handling
            if let error1 = response.error {
                print("error with Login: \(error1)")
            }
        })
```

It is showing this error message :

`Request failed: unauthorized (401) reasons: { errors = ( Unauthorized ); }`

Comment: https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/issues/1070

Answer (score 0):

Error 401 means that authorization is either missing or incorrect. Possible causes are:

- a user tries to authorize with wrong login and password
- a user uses invalid session token

[Here](https://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization#API_User_Sign_In) you can find some more useful information about user sign-in process.

Please refer to this [chat sample](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample-chat-swift) for reference. Specifically, you can check [*AuthViewController.swift*](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/blob/master/sample-chat-swift/sample-chat-swift/Components/Authorization/AuthorizationViewController/AuthorizationViewController.swift) for implementation example:

```
QBRequest.logIn(withUserLogin: login,
            password: password,
            successBlock: { response, user in

            //connectToChat    

      }, errorBlock: { response in
        //handleError
    })
```